# How to view a pdf using iframe from my website?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, permissions

I have pdf files on my website that I would like to show on a page , I tried :

```
<iframe src="https://mywebsite.com/files/file.pdf" frameborder="0" width="600" height="550" style="margin:0px; padding:0px;"></iframe>
```

but the file is downloaded.

I tried using google drive :

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=http://mywebsite.com/files/file.pdf" ></iframe>
```

But I get the html of my login page , I think it automatically redirects to login page.

and I tried to use iframe to access the folder that contains the file:

```
<iframe src="https://mywebsite.com/files" ></iframe>
```

But I get forbidden message that tells me to edit my file permissions .

-Is there is a specific permission that I could use to access the folder or the file?

-Is there is a library , function in any web developing language or anything that could help?