# What is causing the redirection to login page while using iframe?

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess, redirect

I have a website that I want to use iframe to show some pdf files from it but it redirects me to the login page , for example if I try :

```
<iframe src="https://example.com/files/file.pdf"></iframe>
```

Or

```
<iframe src="https://example.com"></iframe>
```

I'm redirected to the login page.

and when I try :

```
 <iframe src="https://example.com/files"></iframe>
```

I get a message saying that this page is forbidden.

What could be causing this redirection ? a script ? .htaccess ? the server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to view a pdf using iframe from my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48717851/how-to-view-a-pdf-using-iframe-from-my-website)

Comment: It's your website, so you should know, we can only guess.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware , I didn't create the script so I'm not sure , I'm asking because i'm not sure what could be controlling everything like that and causing the redirection.

Comment: There's only way to find out: Check all possibilities. Start with the ones you mentioned yourself, before asking the question. In the unlikely event that you cannot find it you can ask a question, and tell us what you've already tried. But even then, we have no way to test any hypothesis we might have, so it's not a good question for SO.